# C++ Load ifstream from string and not file

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

Is it possible to load a string to an ifstream rather than it reading the string from a file? I have a parse function that is limited an ifstream input which would be a pain (or atleast errorprone) to rework into a string input.

Comment: You mean something like a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)?

Comment: Just change the parsing function to take an `std::istream&` as a parameter and then pass an `std::istringstream`? That should not require any "reworking" beyond the change of the function signature.

Comment: The istringstream worked exactly like I wanted. So for future reference for anyone reading. Just set the std::istringstream iss; iss.str(theString);